# Get date from a string

Tags: php, laravel

I have a string like this `G5510ZCU1AQG2`.

the `QG` last letters represent a date formatted like this `2017-07`.

the letter `q` represent the year . and `g` the month.

you keep count the letters to get the number.

I want to get the date from these letters .

I tried to make `switch` statement but its not helpful and there is a lot of code to write.

is there simpler way to get the date as `2017-07` from this string `G5510ZCU1AQG2`?

I'm sorry i'm still learning and i can't think of something useful

Comment: What does the `2` at the end of the string signify, and would there always be just a single digit after the `QG` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes there is always a single digit . its random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do that:

```
$str = "G5510ZCU1AQG2";

$year_letter = substr($str, -3, 1);
$month_letter = substr($str, -2, 1);

$year = 2000 + (ord($year_letter) - ord('A') + 1);
$month = ord($month_letter) - ord('A') + 1;

$date = sprintf("%02d-%d", $month, $year);
```

### Explanation

- First we dig out the letters for year and month using `substr`.
  Passing -3 and 1 means "get me 1 letter which is located 3 away from
  the end".
- Then we get the ASCII code of the letter with `ord()`. Comparing it to the ASCII code of the first letter A gives us the number of the letter in the alphabet (+1 because it starts with 1, not with 0)
- Now that we know the values, we can get the date as `$month . "-" . $year`. However, this would give us 7-2017 and we want a leading zero. That's what the `sprintf` function is used for: `"%02d-%d` means "print a 2-digit number with a leading zero, then a minus sign, then a digit.
- Output of this code: `"07-2017"`

Cheers.